# How do I get a hash slice from a hash of hashes?

Tags: perl, hash, slice, perl-data-structures

I have a hash like so:

```
my %h = ( a => { one => 1,
                 two => 2
             },
          b => { three => 3,
                 four => 4
             },
          c => { five => 5,
                 six => 6
             }
      );

print join(',', @{$h{a}{qw/one two/}});
```

The error I get is:
Can't use an undefined value as an ARRAY reference at q.pl line 17 
which is the line with the print.

What I expected is 
1,2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To get a hash slice from a nested hash, you have to de-reference it in steps. You get the first level that you need:

```
$h{'a'}
```

Now, you have to dereference that as a hash. However, since it's not a simple scalar, you have to put it in braces. To get the whole hash, you'd put a `%` in front of the braces:

```
%{ $h{'a'} }
```

Now you want a slice, so you replace the `%` with an `@`, since you're getting multiple elements, and you also put your keys at the end as normal:

```
@{ $h{'a'} }{ @keys }
```

It might look easier to see the braces separately:

```
@{         }{       }
   $h{'a'}    @keys
```

To make this simpler, v5.20 introduced the [postfix dereference](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2014/09/use-postfix-dereferencing/). Instead of wrapping thing in braces and working from the inside out, you can work from left to right:

```
$h{a}->@{qw/one two/};
```

That `@` is the same thing you saw in front of the first brace. You still know it's a hash slice because a brace follows the sigil.

Answer (score 2):

try

```
print join(',',@{$h{'a'}}{qw/one two/});
```

use of Data::Dumper greatly helps in cases like this one